# Page not scrolling down on mobile version

Tags: html, css, scroll

I hope this finds you well!

I can't seem to figure out why the page of my small page app is not able to scroll down when it hits the media break point for mobile devices.

Here's the link to the pen

https://codepen.io/tiapnn/full/ExVQPzM

Here's my CSS

```
body {
  background-color: darksalmon;
  font-family: 'Sigmar One', cursive;
  overflow-y: scroll
}

#pomodoro-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 550px;
  height: 420px;
  border-radius: 10px;  
  background-color: white;

}

span {
  font-size: xx-large;
  font-family: 'Montserrat Subrayada', sans-serif;
}

header {
  font-size: 45px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  text-align: center;

}

#tomato {
  background-image: url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTTDnWL8S2wxKpTNnFueFEEURgwq5QuF6jJzWQYbV8YUnVJfh-I&usqp=CAU);
  height: 300px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  text-align: center;
}

#timer {
  margin: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

i {
font-size: x-large;
text-align: center;
}

.right-div {
  margin: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;  
}

#timer-label {
  font-family: 'Sigmar One', cursive;
  font-size: 40px;  
  color: white;
}

#time-left {
  font-size: 60px;
  color: white;
}

.lowerI {
  color: white;
  font-size: xx-large;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 575px) {  

  #pomodoro-container {
    height: auto;
    width: 90%;
    top: 10%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0%);

  }

  .right-div {
    padding: 35px;
  }

  header {
    font-size: 40px;
  }


}
```

How can I make it scrollable?

Cheers,
Mattia

P.S: No, I dont have overflow:hidden in my css......

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your line.

## pomodoro-container {

```
position: fixed;
```

remove it :)